# android app project error

Tags: android, eclipse

I keep getting this unable to open trace error in my eclipse android project for some reason. Everything is syntax error free.

here is my log text below.

```
05-20 19:57:02.330: D/AndroidRuntime(30377): Shutting down VM
05-20 19:57:02.330: W/dalvikvm(30377): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
05-20 19:57:02.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30377): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 19:57:02.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30377): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sudoku/com.example.sudoku.Sudoku}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.sudoku.Sudoku in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.sudoku-2.apk]
05-20 19:57:02.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
05-20 19:57:02.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
05-20 19:57:02.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-20 19:57:02.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
05-20 19:57:02.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-20 19:57:02.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-20 19:57:02.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
05-20 19:57:02.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 19:57:02.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-20 19:57:02.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
05-20 19:57:02.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
05-20 19:57:02.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-20 19:57:02.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30377): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.sudoku.Sudoku in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.sudoku-2.apk]
05-20 19:57:02.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
05-20 19:57:02.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
05-20 19:57:02.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
05-20 19:57:02.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
05-20 19:57:02.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
05-20 19:57:02.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    ... 11 more
05-20 19:57:04.352: I/dalvikvm(30377): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
05-20 19:57:04.352: E/dalvikvm(30377): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
05-20 19:57:12.039: I/Process(30377): Sending signal. PID: 30377 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Does your code run in spite of throwing this error?

Comment: Yes the code runs 

But once I run it on my phone the log says its unable to open stack trace file

and my phone says force close app

Comment: And after you force close, does it run normally without additional errors?

Comment: No the app won't open at all anymore

Comment: The LogCat is not helpful, honestly.  I suspected an Eclipse error, not a code error, but when that happens to me, after the force close message, the code works fine, and I've only seen the error testing against an emulator. Try setting breakpoints or sprinkling your code with some Log.d() message to try to isolate the point at which the error occurs.  If you're trying to write to external storage at some point, start your sprinkling there.

Comment: I tried it on the emulator and still doesn't work

Comment: "... still doesn't work" means that the app goes to force close immediately, yes?  Then the manifest is a good place to look. Are you sure you have listed all the permissions you need? Do you need READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE?

Comment: yea the app still goes to force immediately. I tried placing the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE but no luck still.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.sudoku.Sudoku in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.sudoku-2.apk]
```

a `ClassNotFoundException`, maybe you defined it incorrectly in your manifest file.
As you said you have two classes `About.java` and `MainActivity.java` which means that you are trying to define a Sudoku class in the manifest but haven't created it as a java file.

Comment: Below is what I have for the manifest.

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.sudoku"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 
    
    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
          android:label="@string/app_name">

Comment: <activity android:name=".Sudoku"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".About"
              android:label="@string/about_title"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>

Comment: My java classes are: 

About.java
MainActivity.java

My layout is:
about.xml
activity_main.xml

Comment: change name of your MainActivity class to Sudoku

Comment: yes I did thanks..

found out that the main class called Sudoku.java was being layed out wrong. The boolean function had to go on top of the other function. It was kinda more like a logic error most likely.

Answer (score 1):

"My java classes are: About.java MainActivity.java My layout is: about.xml activity_main.xml"
So where is your Sudoku.java class? Maybe you have deleted it accidentally or changed the name of it?

Comment: I changed the part of the manifest where is says: .Sudoku to .MainActivity

But no luck still the app on my phone says unexpectedly have to close

Comment: com.example.sudoku means you project name (sudoku) but com.example.sudoku.Sudoku (which causes an error) means Sudoku.java class, which doesn't exist in your project. Try to clean the project (in eclipse PROJECT > CLEAN). What error do you get after changing to .MainActivity? Try instead to change MainActivity class to Sudoku class.

Comment: Did everything you said. But the app still crashes on the phone.

Comment: Try to uninstall the application from your phone (not only re-install). Uninstall from phone menu then install it again. Also before doing that, restart Eclipse.

Comment: Tried it but still no luck. The app forces out .

Comment: Can you add picture of your manifest file and picture of your class tree (package explorer)? Also look here http://javarevisited.blogspot.jp/2011/08/classnotfoundexception-in-java-example.html

Comment: Yea no problem. http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/9/screenshot20130521at906.png/